# Bind two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, subquery

I have two oracle  select statememts, selecting  data  from same  table.

```
SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount1
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Basic Pay', 'Allowances')
GROUP BY empid, empname, days

SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount2
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Water Charge', 'Housing Allowance') 
GROUP BY empid, empname,tdays
```

I want  to bind  this  to one select  statement  so that  I will get one  resulatant, having  columns empid,empname,days,Amount1,Amount2

Can anyone  please  help me  doing this?
Thanks  in advance.

Comment: If both statements contain the same record do you want duplicates?

Comment: No i  do not  want  duplicates. I want to get columns:empid,empname,days,Amount1 and  Amount2

Comment: Just checking `UNION` should work fine then.  `UNION ALL` would keep the duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below will help you

```
SELECT empid,
   empname,
   days,
   Sum (CASE
          WHEN particulars IN ( 'Water Charge', 'Housing Allowance' ) THEN
          amount
          ELSE 0
        END) Amount2,
   Sum (CASE
          WHEN particulars IN ( 'Basic Pay', 'Allowances' ) THEN 
          amount
          ELSE 0
        END) Amount1
FROM   tbl_details
GROUP  BY empid,
      empname,
      days
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [UNION](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php):

```
SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Basic Pay', 'Allowances')
GROUP BY empid, empname, days
UNION
SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Water Charge', 'Housing Allowance') 
GROUP BY empid, empname,tdays
```

By default a union will eliminate duplicate records, if you would like to keep the duplicate records replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`

Comment: This  gives  me 4  columns  only, last column for  amount2  is  not  displayed.

Comment: Whoops needed to change the name of that last column so it matched.

Answer (score 1):

Try Union

```
SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount1
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Basic Pay', 'Allowances')
GROUP BY empid, empname, days

UNION

SELECT   empid, empname, days, SUM (amount) Amount2
FROM tbl_details
WHERE particulars IN ('Water Charge', 'Housing Allowance') 
GROUP BY empid, empname,tdays
```